# Changing the default screenshot filename

Tags: uti, graphics, screen-capture

Is there a way to change the default screenshot filename prefix (the `Cmd-Shift-4` type screenshot) to something other than the default? The default name looks like this:

```
Screen Shot 2011-08-30 at 10.01.36 AM.png
```

But I'd prefer to use something like:

```
screenshot_2011-08-30_100136.png
```

Basically so I can remove the spaces and junk, since it's annoying to browse dig through files in Terminal. Any easy way to change this prefix with one of the `defaults write com.apple.screencapture` style commands?

Comment: Is there any chance we could get you to select an answer that worked for you? (or an edit to know better what you seek?)

Comment: Similar Info: https://superuser.com/q/339702/247728

Answer (score 12):

You can change 'Screen shot' to 'screenshot' with the following commands

`defaults write com.apple.screencapture name screenshot`
`killall SystemUIServer`

If you want to go digging a bit deeper in Terminal, you can achieve what you want by doing the following:

***NOTE:*** Make a backup of any files you change in case you make a mistake.

1. `cd /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj`
2. Make a copy of the existing file:
   `sudo cp ScreenCapture.strings ScreenCapture.strings.old`
3. Enter Admin password if prompted
4. Convert to an editable format:
   `sudo plutil -convert xml1 ScreenCapture.strings`
5. `sudo vi ScreenCapture.strings`

   Locate the following lines:

   ```
   <key>%@ %@ at %@</key>  
   <string>%@ %@ at %@</string>
   ```

   and replace with the following lines:

   ```
   <key>%@ %@ at %@</key>  
   <string>%@_%@_%@</string>
   ```
6. Convert back to binary:
   `sudo plutil -convert binary1 ScreenCapture.strings`
7. `killall SystemUIServer`

which combined with the first change should get you something like this:

`screenshot_2011-08-30_10.01.36.png` which is very close to what you need I think

Comment: This does not appear to work in OS X El Capitan, presumably due to System Integrity Protection.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this another way. Using Automator I set up a Folder Action to monitor my screen shot folder and rename any new files exactly the way I want them.

There's a decent guide [here](http://snowleopardtips.net/tips/everything-you-need-to-know-about-screen-captures.html) with a similar approach and instructions.

Comment: What's the latency with the Automator approach?  How long between the time the original screencap is saved, and the file is available with the new filename?  Is it 1 second, 3 seconds, 12 seconds?

Comment: Between 5 and 7 seconds from screenshot is taken until the file name is changed (on my MacBook Pro from 2009).

Comment: Thanks! Given that, I'm going to write some bash code to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I have disabled the default shortcuts and [assigned a shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) to this command:

```
screencapture -i ~/Desktop/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).png
```

-i (interactive) is like ⇧⌘4 or ⌃⇧⌘4.

Comment: That seems like the most direct solution to the problem. But how does one map a shortcut to a command? In the System Preferences dialog, it says "enter the exact name of the MENU COMMAND you want to add."  Your command is not a menu command, so...?

Comment: @Cheeso See the link in the answer. You can use an application like FastScripts or Alfred or create a service with Automator.

Answer (score 3):

Open terminal and enter:

```
$ sudo su

$ cd /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj

$ plutil -convert xml1 ScreenCapture.strings

$ nano ScreenCapture.strings
```

change

```
<key>%@ %@ at %@</key>
    <string>%@ %@ at %@</string>
<key>.</key>
    <string>.</string>
<key>Screen Shot</key>
    <string>Screen Shot</string>
```

to

```
<key>%@ %@ at %@</key>
    <string>%@_%@_%@</string>
<key>.</key>
    <string></string>
<key>Screen Shot</key>
    <string>screenshot</string>
```

then

<kbd>Control</kbd> + O to write the file, and <kbd>Control</kbd> + X to exit nano

```
$ plutil -convert binary1 ScreenCapture.strings

$ killall SystemUIServer
```

One more thing to note here is that to get rid of AM/PM you will need to change it in System Preferences > Language & Text > Formats (24 hour format). Time stamps are displayed according to how this is set; keep in mind if you change this setting all filenames will use this format.

~ Let me know how it works out.

Answer (score 3):

The same effect of the complicated terminal actions shown above can be achieved through the free [secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) preference pane, which serves as an interface for all sorts of hidden setting in Mac OS and it's apps. Simply open the pref pane and find the setting u want to change

Answer (score 1):

IMO you should absolutely not muck around with anything in /System/.

For one thing, you are just asking for your customizations to be overwritten by a future update.

Download the demo of Sharpshooter from http://www.kerlmax.com/products/sharpshooter/

You can use it for 30 days. Then buy it for $15. It's a great utility.

Alternatively, have you tried [Skitch](https://skitch.com/)? It's completely free, and a lot better than the built-in.

Answer (score 1):

I liked [Adrian B's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/88494/27434). Here's the shell script I wrote to rename screen cap files: https://gist.github.com/DinoChiesa/7796444

To set it up as a Folder Action, follow [this article](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_use_folder_actions_automator).

When you get to the Automator window, follow this guide:

[image]

Don't forget to save it (Command-S).

It takes 3-6 seconds, in my experience, for that folder action to "kick off" after I capture the screen.

Answer (score 1):

just use 2 commands:

```
d̶e̶f̶a̶u̶l̶t̶s̶ ̶w̶r̶i̶t̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶.̶a̶p̶p̶l̶e̶.̶s̶c̶r̶e̶e̶n̶c̶a̶p̶t̶u̶r̶e̶ ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶"̶s̶c̶r̶e̶e̶n̶s̶h̶o̶t̶_̶$̶(̶d̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶+̶%̶Y̶_̶%̶m̶_̶%̶d̶-̶%̶H̶_̶%̶M̶_̶%̶S̶)̶"̶ ̶
d̶e̶f̶a̶u̶l̶t̶s̶ ̶w̶r̶i̶t̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶.̶a̶p̶p̶l̶e̶.̶s̶c̶r̶e̶e̶n̶c̶a̶p̶t̶u̶r̶e̶ ̶"̶i̶n̶c̶l̶u̶d̶e̶-̶d̶a̶t̶e̶"̶ ̶0̶
```

you can also change the default screenshot location (in my case this is a folder in iCloud)

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location "~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/screenshots"
```

Comment: This worked the first time, but every subsequent screenshot just repeated the first name and appended an incremented number to the end.

Comment: @BrettVanderVeen yes you're right, it's not a solution