# Can I have macOS prompt for the filename of a screenshot?

Tags: screen-capture

I like the native screenshot functionality that comes with macOS. I know one can configure the **folder** location and even filename prefix of each screenshot, but I would like to use a dedicated shortcut for screenshots where I want to easily specify the **filename** of the screenshot itself at the moment of saving it (ideally shortcut + region selection + name + enter).

Is this doable with the screenshot features that come with macOS?

Comment: doesnt look like it, but you can make a simple automator workflow for that I guess https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27729/changing-the-default-screenshot-filename?rq=1

Comment: Can you describe your exact workflow? If every filename is going to need typing in, does in matter at what point you do it?